# Como identificar valores en un string

Tags: javascript, java, python, regex, shell-script

estamos realizando validadores de expresiones las cuales se encuentran cargadas en una base de datos.
El desafio es tomar dicha expresion, por ejemplo:

```
Objeto.getNombreFuncion("123").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta") && 
Objeto.getNombreFuncion("Otra_Etiqueta").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta")
```

y separar todo lo que se encuentra entre comillas, deberia quedar algo asi:

```
 123
    Nombre_Etiqueta
    Otra_Etiqueta
    Nombre_Etiqueta
```

Estamos pensando ulizar python, pero cualquier lenguaje es bienvenido.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que cualquier lenguaje te puede proporcionar una solución sencilla, por ejemplo con JavaScript.

Los pasos que yo tomaría serían:

1. Asignar el contenido en una variable
2. Realizar un split de el contenido para que me cree un array con los elementos, tomando como símbolo las comillas.
3. Crear un array con los nuevos valores, con un salto intercalado de líneas (es decir una línea sí y la otra no)

Lo que sería:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="ObtenerDatos()">Procesar</button>
  <script>
     function ObtenerDatos() {
     var datos = 'Objeto.getNombreFuncion("123").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta") && Objeto.getNombreFuncion("Otra_Etiqueta").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta")';
     var lineas = datos.split('"');
     var resultado = [];

     for (i = 1; i < lineas.length; i += 2) {
       resultado.push(lineas[i]);
      }

     for (i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
       console.log(resultado[i]);
     }
   }
 </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Puedes verlo funcionando dese aqui https://plnkr.co/edit/dlbPQIKPfp6Nnq3BoX9k?p=preview

Recuerda abrir la consola para ver los resultados

Answer (score 0):

En Python sería algo así:

```
string = 'Objeto.getNombreFuncion("123").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta") && Objeto.getNombreFuncion("Otra_Etiqueta").getAttribute("Nombre_Etiqueta")'

datos = string.split('"')

for i in range(1, len(datos), 2):
    print(datos[i])
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: O también `datos = string.split('"')[1::2]`

Comment: Pero ten en cuenta que no funcionará si dentro de las comillas pueden aparecer a su vez comillas (escapadas por algún método que puede depender de la base de datos)